# Explicit join to implicit join sql

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am new to SQL and been trying to write a query using explicit JOIN for it's better performance over implicit JOIN

```
SELECT 
r.TicketNumber,
r.VendorNumber,
r.VendorName,
rd.FromCityCode,
rd.ToCityName,
et.TravelDate,
tc.TotalAmount,
tc.AmountInvoiced,
FROM Reservations as r,
ReservationDetails as rd,
Trips as t,
TripCosts as tc
WHERE r.ProductCode='1'
AND t.TravelDate < '2016-11-23 00:00:00.0'
AND t.TravelDate > '2016-10-23 00:00:00.0'
AND t.TripID = r.TripID
AND r.ReservationID=rd.ReservationID
AND t.TripID = tc.TripID;
```

When I turn it into INNER JOIN

```
SELECT 
r.TicketNumber,
r.VendorNumber,
r.VendorName,
rd.FromCityCode,
rd.ToCityName,
t.TravelDate,
tb.TotalAmount,
tb.AmountInvoiced
FROM Reservations as r
  JOIN ReservationDetails as rd ON rd.ReservationID=r.ReservationID
  JOIN Trips as t ON TripID = r.TripID
  JOIN TripBalances as tb ON tb.TripID = t.TripID
WHERE r.ProductCode='1'
AND t.TravelDate < '2016-11-23 00:00:00.0'
AND t.TravelDate > '2016-10-23 00:00:00.0'
```

When I run the Inner join query, I am getting

```
Error: Ambiguous column name 'TripID'.
SQLState:  S0001
ErrorCode: 209
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are missing `alias` name in `TripID`

```
JOIN Trips as t ON t.TripID = r.TripID
                 --^here
```

Also there is no performance gain in using one over the another. Explicit Join is more readable then the implicit join. Both will have identical execution plans

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out my silly mistake. Another question, what's the cleanest way to create such long  queries in Java, instead of using String ?? Is there a better way?
Thanks

Comment: @user2070333 - Am a database guy not sure about Java